# ASP.NET MVC Login Not Sticking

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, simplemembership

I'm having an issue with my ASP.NET MVC 5 simple membership provider login code. The code is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        bool active = true;

        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.Email, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            UserDetail userModel = UserDetail.Initialize(model.Email);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, true);

            active = userModel.ActiveBit;

            if (active)
            {
                return Redirect("~/");
            }
            else
            {
                WebSecurity.Logout();
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Account is inactive.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "*Either the Username or Password provided is incorrect.");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

The login processes successfully and I can see the authentication cookie (.ASPXAUTH) in the browser. The problem arises on the next page request. The authentication cookie is passed back to the server, but the server seems to have no record of the login any more. When I set a breakpoint and check after processing the login and requesting a new page (after completing the post-login redirect), User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false as is WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated and WebSecurity.HasUserID. WebSecurity.CurrentUserId is -1 and WebSecurity.CurrentUserName is an empty string.

It's not a database connectivity issue since I do authenticate successfully. I do a roundtrip to the server and back and I am still not authenticated so the common answers I've seen for CurrentUser == -1 don't seem to apply.

I'm a relative newbie on MVC but I had a coworker who's got a decent amount experience on this look at my code and he couldn't find anything either. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default asp.net MVC5 web.config not supporting `FormsAuthentication`, check below section of your web config file and remove `"<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />"` if you want to use FormsAuthentication.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Authentication timeout configuration

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about the timeout? <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>

Comment: Timeout's 480 minutes.